# NLP: How do I combine stemming and tagging?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tagging, stemming

I'm trying to write code which passes in text that has been tokenized and had the stop words filtered out, and then stems and tags it. However, I'm not sure in what order I should stem and tag. This is what I have at the moment:

```
#### Stemming
ps = PorterStemmer()    # PorterStemmer imported from nltk.stem

stemText = []

for word in swFiltText:    # Tagged text w/o stop words
    stemText.append(ps.stem(word))


#### POS Tagging
def tagging():
    tagTot = []
    try:
        for i in stemText:
            words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)    # I need to tokenize again (idk why?)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
            tagTot = tagTot + tagged    # Combine tagged words into list

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    return tagTot

tagText = tagging()
```

At first glance, this works just fine. However, because I stemmed first, `pos_tag` often mislabels words. For example, it marked "hous" as an adjective, when the original word was really the noun "house". But when I try to stem after tagging, it gives me an error about how `pos_tag` can't deal with 'tuples' - I'm guessing this has something to do with the way that the stemmer formats the word list as `[('come', 'VB'), ('hous', 'JJ')`, etc.

Should I be using a different stemmer/tagger? Or is the error in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using lemmatization over stemming, stemming just chops off letters from the end until the root/stem word is reached. Lemmatization also looks at the surrounding text to determine the given words's part of speech.

Comment: Oh, so lemmatization tags it too? I didn't realize that!

Comment: I just did a quick search on this online and I found a site suggesting I use WordNet or TextBlob. Do you tend to use one or the other? 
Here's the site if you want to take a look at it: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/lemmatization-examples-python/

Comment: Hi @MollyTaylor, yes it does!

Comment: Lemmatising and tagging are two separate procedures. Some applications might combine the two tasks for improved results (see details in my response)

Answer (score 1):

You should tag the text *before* you apply stemming or lemmatisation to it.

Removing the endings of words takes away crucial clues about what part-of-speech tag a word can be.

The reason that you got *hous* as an adjective is that any tagger expects unprocessed tokens, and words ending in *-ous* in English are usually adjectives (*nefarious*, *serious*). If you tag it first, it can be recognises (even without context) as either a noun or a verb. The tagger can then use context (preceded by *the*? -> noun) to disambiguate which is the most likely one.

A good lemmatiser can take the part-of-speech into account, eg *housing* could be a noun (lemma: *housing*) or a verb (lemma: *house*). With p-o-s information a lemmatiser can make the correct choice there.

Whether you use stemming or lemmatisation depends on your application. For many purposes they will be equivalent. The main difference from my experience are that:

1. Stemming is a lot faster, as stemmers have a few rules on how to handle various endings
2. Lemmatisation gives you 'proper' words which you can look up in dictionaries (if you want to get glosses in other languages or definitions)
3. Stemmed strings sometimes don't look anything like the original word, and if you present them to a human user they might get confused
4. Stemmers conflate words which have similar meanings but different lemmas, so for information retrieval they might be more useful
5. Stemmers don't need a word list, so if you want to write your own stemmer, it's quicker than writing a lemmatiser (if you're processing languages for which no ready-made tools exist)

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense. I'm now working with lemmatization, and I can't figure out how to get chunking to work with it. It would mean the world to me if you could take a look at my problem on [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/g71o07/anyone_know_nlpnltk_im_learning_lemmatizing/).